# How do I find the average of integer value from the list consisting of triples of strings and integers?

Tags: scheme, racket

I need some help with a homework problem. The problem says to write a nonrecursive  averageAge function that takes a list of persons and a string “employed” or “unemployed” as arguments and returns the average age persons in the list with the given employment status.

I have written the following code but the code only extracts the matching values from the list. The sumList is to add the sum of the integer values:

```
(define sumList
  (lambda(lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        0
        (+ (car lst)(sumList (cdr lst)))
        )))

(define (averageAge lst s)
  (filter (lambda(x) (equal? (caddr x) s)) lst))

(define lst '( (joe  21  "employed")  ( ann 19 "unemployed")  (sue 18 "employed" )  ))
```

The code extracts the following values from the list

```
 >>(averageAge lst "employed")
 >>'((joe 21 "employed") (sue 18 "employed"))
```

I do not know how to approach from here to get the following output. Any help would be appreciated.

```
>>(averageAge  lst  “employed”) 
>>19.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution by *composing* the `sumList` procedure together with other higher-order procedures. Basically, we need to:

- Find the list of elements that satisfies the condition - the `filter` part in your code is already doing this.
- Call `sumList` on the ages present on the previous result, `map` comes in handy for extracting them.
- Divide by the length of the list from the first result - assuming is non-empty.

A couple of details need to be taken care of:

- We should store the filtered list in a variable, to avoid recalculating it. We can use `let` for this.
- We need to handle the case when the filtered list is empty (left as an exercise for the reader.)
- Optionally, convert the result to decimals (use `exact->inexact` for this.)

It'll be a simple matter for you to fill-in the remaining details:

```
(define (averageAge lst s)
  (let ((filtered-by-status (filter (lambda (x) (equal? (caddr x) s)) lst)))
    (/ (sumList (map cadr filtered-by-status))
       (length filtered-by-status))))
```